# SYNCH databases customization

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, asp.net-web-api

**Existing Application**:
I have an existing distributed Windows Forms application which is developed using VS 2013 & SQL Server 2008. Application is communicating through web api's from various remote locations to the central database.

**Requirement/Feature:**
1. I have to add new feature that application may be run in offline mode if there is no internet connectivity. When application is connected to the internet it should SYNCH all the data automatically to the server. Also if there are any changes to the database server in central database it should be SYNCH to remote locations as well.

2. The synch mechanism must use the webapis to synch the data and database structure.

**My Proposal:**
I'm planning to use Microsoft SYNCH framework to add SYNCH feature but it can not be done through webapi's (It has to be done through API's as per client requirement).
Also we need complete audit/reporting of the SYNCH process and hence this can not be done without customizing the program for adding SYNCH feature and we can not use Micorsoft SYNCH framework.

My Question/Queries

1. Can anyone suggest the best approach to do this so that both data and architecture can be SYNCH?
2. Would be great if anyone has used the generic approach which may be used for all database tables?

Thank you very much in advance!!